# Problema al guardar información en una Base de Datos

Tags: android, sql

les pido su ayuda porque ya llevo varios días tronandome la cabeza con este programa, lo explico de manera sencilla:

Es un programa que muestra algunos datos de acuerdo a una solicitud por parte del usuario. Se supone que debe de poder guardar un historial de lo realizado, pero ese es el problema, no guarda y lo he intentado por varios métodos y nada, recurro a su experiencia y sabiduría, espero que alguien pueda iluminarme....

Les dejo parte del código, `BDayuda`  que extiende de `SQLiteOpenHelper`  :

```
package com.example.erickcr.discursospblicos;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


class BDayuda extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_mainero.db";

    String sqlCreate1="CREATE TABLE discursos(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, discurso TEXT)";
    String sqlCreate2="CREATE TABLE canciones(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, cancion TEXT, base TEXT)";
    String sqlCreate3="CREATE TABLE historia(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, fecha TEXT, hno TEXT, n_disc TEXT, cong TEXT, n_can TEXT)";
    Context ctx;
    public BDayuda(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        ctx=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate1);
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate2);
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS discursos");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS canciones");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS historia");
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate1);
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate2);
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate3);
    }

    BDayuda ayuda;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public void abrir_db(){
        ayuda=new BDayuda(ctx);
        db=ayuda.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    public void cerrar_db(){
        db.close();
    }

    public long registrar (ContentValues dato) throws Exception{
        return db.insert("historia",null,dato);
    }
}
```

Mi archivo Activity3 :

```
package com.example.erickcr.discursospblicos;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Bundle bolsaR;
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6;
    EditText fecha;
    Button btn_reg;
    int año, mes, dia;
    static final int TIPO_DIALOGO=0;
    static DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener oyenteSelectorFecha;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);
        tv1= findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2= findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3= findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        tv4= findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        tv5= findViewById(R.id.tv5);
        tv6= findViewById(R.id.tv6);
        btn_reg=findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);
        ////////////cuadro de fecha
        fecha=findViewById(R.id.fecha);
        Calendar calendario=Calendar.getInstance();
        dia=calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes=calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        año=calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        mostrarfecha();
        oyenteSelectorFecha=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                dia=dayOfMonth;
                mes=month;
                año=year;
                mostrarfecha();

            }
        };
///////// Fin del cuadro de fecha

        bolsaR=getIntent().getExtras();

        String path = null;
        try {
            path = db_directorio();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {       checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

                    tv1.setText(bolsaR.getString("can"));
                    String[] n2= new String[]{(bolsaR.getString("can"))};

                    Cursor c1 = checkDB.rawQuery("SELECT cancion,base FROM canciones WHERE _id=?",n2);
                    if(c1.moveToFirst()){
                        String can1=c1.getString(0);
                        String can2=c1.getString(1);
                        String can3=can1+"\n"+can2;
                        tv2.setText(can3);}

                    String[] n1= new String[]{(bolsaR.getString("dis"))};

                    Cursor c = checkDB.rawQuery("SELECT discurso FROM discursos WHERE _id=?",n1);
                    if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    String datos=c.getString(0);
                         tv6.setText(datos);}

            checkDB.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

        tv4.setText(bolsaR.getString("nom"));
        tv5.setText(bolsaR.getString("con"));
        fecha.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        btn_reg.setEnabled(true);
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////FIN DEL MAIN/////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////// FUNCIONES ///////////////////////////////////////
    public void mostrarfecha(){
        fecha.setText(año+"/"+(mes+1)+"/"+dia);
        }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id){
            case 0:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,oyenteSelectorFecha,año,mes,dia);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void mostrarcalendario(View control){
        showDialog(TIPO_DIALOGO);
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void btn_historia(View control){
        String path = null;
        try {
            path = db_directorio();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Integer d0=null;
        String d1=fecha.getText().toString();
        String d2=(bolsaR.getString("nom"));
        String d3=(bolsaR.getString("dis"));
        String d4=(bolsaR.getString("con"));
        String d5=tv1.getText().toString();

        ContentValues nuevoRegistro = new ContentValues();
        nuevoRegistro.put("_id", d0);
        nuevoRegistro.put("fecha", d1);
        nuevoRegistro.put("hno",d2);
        nuevoRegistro.put("n_disc",d3);
        nuevoRegistro.put("cong",d4);
        nuevoRegistro.put("n_can",d5);
try{
        BDayuda bda=new BDayuda(this);
        bda.abrir_db();
        long registrar = bda.registrar(nuevoRegistro);
        bda.cerrar_db();
     if (registrar>0){
         Toast.makeText(this, "Valor insertado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB;
    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

       checkDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO historia (_id, fecha, hno, n_disc, cong, n_can)"+" VALUES ("+d0+" ,'"+d1+"' ,'"+d2+"' ,'"+d3+"' ,'"+d4+"' ,'"+d5+"')");

        btn_reg.setEnabled(false);
        checkDB.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

    }

    public String db_directorio() throws IOException {
        InputStream in = getAssets().open("db_mainero.db");
        File outFile = new File(getFilesDir().getPath() +"/db_mainero.db");
        Log.d("paaath", outFile.getAbsolutePath());
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        String path1 = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/db_mainero.db";
        return path1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Erik, no importa si eres "novato", creo que todos somos "novatos" ya que nunca dejamos de aprender, simplemente recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask] y así obtendrás la ayuda requerida. ¿ Como guardas los datos, mediante el método registrar() ?, ¿Revisaste el LogCat por algún posible error,posiblemente SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException?

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, si puedes notar en el codigo, intente hacer por la funcion registrar y obtuve un long positivo dando a entender que si estaba entrando. Tambien lo hago de manera manual con el    `checkDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO`   y en mi proyecto tengo guardada la base en asset, pero aun asi use una funcion de busqueda para poder usar de manera correcta la base, uso la variable path y la funcion db_directorio en la activity3. y creo que tu respuesta de los permisos tiene logica, pues si puedo leer pero no escribir. Hare pruebas, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

**Primeramente debes verificar tengas especificado el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`**, en este caso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Recuerda que si tu dispositivo tiene sistema operativo Android 6.0 o posterior, debes requerir este permiso manualmente:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
     checkExternalStoragePermission();
}
```

Puedes usar este método:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

---

Si tienes permisos, ahora debes obtener la ruta correcta de la base de datos, puedo notar que usas

```
InputStream in = getAssets().open("db_mainero.db");
```

pero en realidad la base de datos no se esta creando dentro de /assets , para obtener correctamente la ruta de la base de datos realiza lo siguiente:

#### Obtener la ruta de base de datos en Android

Para obtener la ruta de la base de datos puedes usar el método [getDatabasePath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)), indicando el nombre de la base de datos :

```
String dbname = "myDatabase.db";
Path dbpath = getDatabasePath(dbname);
```